# Skyrim Standard to Legendary Save Transfer - Xbox

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have the XBox standard version of Skyrim. If I bought the Legendary Edition *on disc*, would I be able to use the old saves with the new DLC? I know you can buy and download the DLC, but I am looking to use the the retail L.E..

Similar to the question here,
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/66294427
but I am not sure about console (XBox) Platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use your non-L.E. saves, even if you didn't have the DLC when the saves were made with the original game.

(Sources: QA Tester, [Amazon Review](http://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1VSDDZYW4ARDS/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00CJ7IUGS), [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130718125302AAZ4pyE))

Comment: Do I have to do anything for L.E. to  read the standard saves? I went to buy L.E. a while back at retail, and they said that the XBox reads them as two different games, so the standard saves cannot be read on L.E.

Comment: I think the people you were speaking to were misinformed--the console does not consider LE a different version of the game. The retail version of LE has two discs: the first is the original game (exactly the same as what came out on 11/11/11), and the second has all the DLC and patches. You can just use disc 2 to install the DLC/Patches on top of a non-LE Skyrim install if you want, as it's effectively the same thing.